# ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException. Again:(

Tags: ios, swift2, researchkit

I know that this question was asked so many times and I read answers, but still can't fix my problem.
So, here is **class SurveyTask**.

```
public class SurveyTask: NSObject, ORKTask {

let introStepID = "intro_step"
let nameStepID = "name_step"
let questStepID = "quest_step"
let colorStepID = "color_step"
let summaryStepID = "summary_step"

public var identifier: String { get { return "survey"} }

public func stepBeforeStep(step: ORKStep?, withResult result: ORKTaskResult) -> ORKStep? {

    switch step?.identifier {
    case .Some(nameStepID):
        return stepWithIdentifier(introStepID)

    case .Some(questStepID):
        return stepWithIdentifier(nameStepID)

    case .Some(summaryStepID):
        return questStep(findName(result))

    default:
        return nil
    }
}

public func stepAfterStep(step: ORKStep?, withResult result: ORKTaskResult) -> ORKStep? {

    switch step?.identifier {
    case .None:
        return stepWithIdentifier(introStepID)

    case .Some(introStepID):
        return stepWithIdentifier(nameStepID)

    case .Some(nameStepID):
        return questStep(findName(result))

    case .Some(questStepID):
        return stepWithIdentifier(summaryStepID)

    default:
        return nil
    }
}

public func stepWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> ORKStep? {
    switch identifier {

    case introStepID:
        let instructionStep = ORKInstructionStep(identifier: introStepID)
        instructionStep.title = "The Questions Three"
        instructionStep.text = "Who would cross the Bridge of Death must answer me these questions three, ere the other side they see."
        return instructionStep

    case nameStepID:
        let nameAnswerFormat = ORKTextAnswerFormat(maximumLength: 20)
        nameAnswerFormat.multipleLines = false
        let nameQuestionStepTitle = "What is your name?"
        return ORKQuestionStep(identifier: nameStepID, title: nameQuestionStepTitle, answer: nameAnswerFormat)

    case questStepID:
        return questStep("")

    case summaryStepID:
        let summaryStep = ORKCompletionStep(identifier: "SummaryStep")
        summaryStep.title = "Right. Off you go!"
        summaryStep.text = "That was easy!"
        return summaryStep

    default:
        return nil
    }
}

func findName(result: ORKTaskResult) -> String? {

    if let stepResult = result.resultForIdentifier(nameStepID) as? ORKStepResult, let subResults = stepResult.results, let textQuestionResult = subResults[0] as? ORKTextQuestionResult {

        return textQuestionResult.textAnswer
    }
    return nil
}

func questStep(name: String?) -> ORKStep {

    var questQuestionStepTitle = "What is your quest?"

    if let name = name {
        questQuestionStepTitle = "What is your quest, \(name)?"
    }

    let textChoices = [
        ORKTextChoice(text: "Create a ResearchKit App", value: 0),
        ORKTextChoice(text: "Seek the Holy Grail", value: 1),
        ORKTextChoice(text: "Find a shrubbery", value: 2)
    ]
    let questAnswerFormat: ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat = ORKAnswerFormat.choiceAnswerFormatWithStyle(.SingleChoice, textChoices: textChoices)
    return ORKQuestionStep(identifier: questStepID, title: questQuestionStepTitle, answer: questAnswerFormat)
}}
```

In **viewController**:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let activity = Activity(rawValue: indexPath.row) else { return }

    let taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController
    switch activity {
        case .Survey:
            taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: SurveyTask(), taskRunUUID: nil)
        }
    taskViewController.delegate = self
    navigationController?.presentViewController(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And when I Build&Run my project and push on Survey it started(!) and I see first step from survey, but when I tapped "Get started" It stopped on condition in **findName** function(I added an image to better show where it stopped http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image1020309.png):

```
func findName(result: ORKTaskResult) -> String? {

    if let stepResult = result.resultForIdentifier(nameStepID) as? ORKStepResult, let subResults = stepResult.results, let textQuestionResult = subResults[0] as? ORKTextQuestionResult {//////here

        return textQuestionResult.textAnswer
    }
    return nil
}
```

You are right, @conarch, an array, which I'm trying to access is really empty. But I can't understand why it is empty. I want to do a "dependent" survey(the answer to the previous question determines what would be the next question). For that I need to get result of question.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: I done steps that described in this post(add exception breakpoint) , Build&Run my project, push survey and then get started and it stopped in this position:
' func findName(result: ORKTaskResult) -> String? {

    if let stepResult = result.resultForIdentifier(nameStepID) as? ORKStepResult, let subResults = stepResult.results, let textQuestionResult = subResults[0] as? ORKTextQuestionResult {////here

        return textQuestionResult.textAnswer
    }
    return nil
}'

Whats wrong with that function?

Comment: In Xcode, go to the debugging pane (the window on the left, the tab icon that is second from the right and looks like, well, a breakpoint).  In the bottom of that pane, tap on the + symbol and "Add Exception Breakpoint..."  Now when you crash, you should be stopped in a more helpful location.

Comment: I i said that I already did it .

**I done steps that described in this post(add exception breakpoint)** , Build&Run my project, push survey and then get started and it stopped in this position: ' func findName(result: ORKTaskResult) -> String? { if let stepResult = result.resultForIdentifier(nameStepID) as? ORKStepResult, let subResults = stepResult.results, let textQuestionResult = subResults[0] as? ORKTextQuestionResult {////here return textQuestionResult.textAnswer } return nil }' Whats wrong with that function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't often read the comments as closely as the actual question.  You should update your original post to include that info.  You should also post the actual text of the error message (the actual exception).  But guessing, I suspect you may be accessing element 0 of an empty array, thus getting an "out of range" exception.

Comment: I can't see enough to know how/when/where you populate the content of the result object, but one way to avoid the crash is to move the array access from that first "if" statement.  Instead, update the "if" to have a "where subResults.count > 0".  Then, inside the "if", you can safely access element 0.

Comment: I see the `subResults` has zero elements too.